# Python, animate a function with two arguments

Tags: python, function, animation, matplotlib

I am new to python so I understand that this may be a stupid question, but I am having issues animating this. I can't see what the error is. I get this error 
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: '

I want to use matplotlib when animating, because I have not downloaded scitools.

Any help at all would be very much appriciated

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

x = np.linspace(-6, 6)
tmax = 1
tmin = -1
t = np.linspace(-1, 1)

def f(x, t):
    term = (np.exp(-1*(x-3*t)**2))*np.sin(3*np.pi*(x-t))
    return term
max_f = f(x[-1], t[-1])
plt.ion()
y = f(x, tmax)
lines = plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axis([x[0], x[-1], -0.1, max_f])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f')

counter = 0
for ts in t:
    y = f(x, t)
    lines[0].set_ydata(y)
    plt.legend(['ts=%4.2f' % ts])
    plt.draw()
    plt.savefig('tmp_%04d.png' % counter)
    counter += 1


fig = plt.figure()

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, f, interval = 1000, blit=True)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([x[0], x[-1], -0.1, max_f])
lines = plt.plot([], [])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f')

plt.show()
```

EDIT, full traceback:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1699, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 745, in callit
    func(*args)

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 370, in idle_draw
    self.draw()

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 351, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 464, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1151, in draw
    self.canvas.draw_event(renderer)

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1823, in draw_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, event)

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 554, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 416, in **call**
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 881, in _start
    self._init_draw()

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1540, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))

File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1562, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)

TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'

Comment: You might want to identify the line that's giving you the error.

Comment: Please post the full traceback, not just the error.

Comment: Also, edit the question.

Comment: The code is completely different from the usual [FuncAnimation examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html). Even if it was running without error, it would not produce an animation. maybe you want to take a step back end make sure that the design of the code makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

As said, this is not really about the error, you can easily prevent that by supplying some value for `t` as `fargs` in FuncAnimation. However, this will not lead to the code producing an animation at all and hence as said, start with the [exmaple](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html) add your functions and code step by step and see what happens.

This will eventually lead to something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.linspace(-6, 6)
tmax = 1
tmin = -1
t = np.linspace(-1, 1)

def f(x, t):
    term = (np.exp(-1*(x-3*t)**2))*np.sin(3*np.pi*(x-t))
    return term

y = f(x, tmax)
lines = plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axis([x[0], x[-1], -1, 1])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f')

counter = [0]
def animate(ts):
    y = f(x, ts)
    lines[0].set_ydata(y)
    plt.legend(['ts=%4.2f' % ts])
    #plt.savefig('tmp_%04d.png' % counter)
    counter[0] += 1

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames = t, interval = 1000)
plt.show()
```

[image]